# iPhone 5 screen issues in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am facing the below issue with the iPhone 5 screen display while using the latest Xcode 5.02

My buttons, which are all at the bottom of the screen (say Screen2), are not working (meaning, though its visible, its not been triggered upon touching)

**Setups / Scenarios:**

**A)** I configured ‘Default-568h@2x.png’

**B)** My very first screen (ie.Screen1) is working fine as expected. (All the buttons working fine in the entire screen)

**C)** Upon clicking a button, I am invoking Screen2. (I configured the Screen2 with the size property as **‘Retina 4 inch Full Screen’**)

**D)** Its opening the screen2 and displays everything as expected but the buttons at the bottom (which are visible also) are not triggered upon touching. I understood somehow the touch sensitivity is working in the 3.5 inch screen area, but not below that.

**E)** Now I clicked the ‘Close’ button which is at the top of the screen opens the earlier screen1, now noticed the screen1 also behaving like the screen2 now (Meaning, buttons at the bottom are not triggered, earlier it was ok)

**F)** I also tried to put 'Auto Layout' still the results are same.

**G)** I am using two versions of XIB to support both 3.5 and 4 inch screens. 3.5 works well.

**P.S:** I am testing the above with **iOS7 & the latest Xcode 5.0.2**

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code? It seemes that you view are creating as a iPhone 3.5 inch view. Can you try to check the frame in the awakeFromNib?

Comment: Thanks. Your question triggered me to check again. Actually interms of screen height it is perfect and shows 568 only, however in my screen, I was using a spl transition which has a contentPanel with the height of old 480 which has the 568 height view.... Now rectified thanks.